# multi-variable chain rule notation question

Tags: complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

> If $z = f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives then
>
> $$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \Delta x + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\Delta y$$

I have not seen the chain rule written this way before, but I am studying complex analysis and trying to prove the converse of Cauchy Riemann's equations is true if all the partial derivatives exist and are continuous. This form is used in the textbooks proof and I do not recognize it or understand where it comes from.

For $z = f(x(t), y(t))$, I'm used to seeing:

$$
\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial t}
$$

What is the relationship between the two? And what does "$dz$" mean by itself?

Comment: With the delta's in that formula, this is more of a linear approximation formula than some formula for the partial derivatives.

Comment: @Paul Is it something to do with the Taylor expansion of a multi-variable function? My professor mentioned it, but it's not utilized or referenced in the textbook. The book does reference an advanced calculus text in the footer of the proof, but I found that book and still can't find where they are getting it.

Comment: Yes, the linear approximation is the same as the first order Taylor approximation.

Comment: Please include the reference where it appears. It would be appropriate to identify $\mathbb{C}=\mathbb{R}^2$  and treat $f\colon \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ to deal with Cauchy Riemann equations.

Comment: See this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/398090/289217

Comment: instead of $$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \Delta x + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\Delta y,$$ should be $$\Delta z = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \Delta x + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\Delta y,$$ or $$dz = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}dy.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dz is the total differential of z. I always try to think of it as measuring the total infinitesimal change in z due to both x and y. I like to read it as follows:

“dz= (the change of z wrt x)*(a small change in x) + (the change of z wrt y)*(a small change in y) “